# Unexpected message - no endpoint registered with connection interceptor

Tags: java, spring, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

I am recently testing tcp ip communication with Spring. The problem I am having occurs while receiving a packet from the ip i connect to.

Below is the Application (pretty similiar to [DynamicTcpClientApplication](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/dynamictcp/DynamicTcpClientApplication.java) with a few changes by myself for testing reasons.

What am I doing wrong, I have an adapter for receiving messages but it seems, only the messages sent from my server wont reach them. Please tell me if there is an issue with my client.

This is giving me a headache....

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMessageHistory
public class ClientApplication {

    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ClientApplication.class);
        builder.headless(false);
        context = builder.run(args);
        new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientConfiguration config() {
        File file = new File(Paths.getInstallationFolder() + File.separator + "client.properties");
        if (!file.exists())
            try {
                if (file.createNewFile()) {
                    Logger.getLogger("Client").warning("Properties not found! New properties created." +
                            "Please restart the application!");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            return new ClientConfiguration(Paths.getInstallationFolder().getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (ConfigurationException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(10));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }

    // Client side

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "toTcp.input")
    public interface ToTCP {

        void send(String data, @Header("host") String host, @Header("port") int port);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow toTcp() {
        return f -> f.route(new TcpRouter());
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetServerConnectionFactory cf() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(6666);
        factory.setSingleUse(false);
        ByteArrayCrLfSerializer serializer = (ByteArrayCrLfSerializer) factory.getSerializer();
        serializer.setMaxMessageSize(20480);
        ByteArrayCrLfSerializer deserializer = (ByteArrayCrLfSerializer) factory.getDeserializer();
        deserializer.setMaxMessageSize(20480);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inbound(AbstractServerConnectionFactory cf) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter messageHandler = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        messageHandler.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        messageHandler.setOutputChannel(outputChannel());
        messageHandler.setAutoStartup(true);
        messageHandler.start();
        return messageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueChannel outputChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "outputChannel", outputChannel = "serviceChannel")
    @Bean
    public ObjectToStringTransformer transformer() {
        return new ObjectToStringTransformer();
    }


    public static class TcpRouter extends AbstractMessageRouter {


        @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
        @Autowired
        private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

        private final static int MAX_CACHED = 10; // When this is exceeded, we remove the LRU.

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        private final LinkedHashMap<String, MessageChannel> subFlows =
                new LinkedHashMap<String, MessageChannel>(MAX_CACHED, .75f, true) {

                    @Override
                    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<String, MessageChannel> eldest) {
                        if (size() > MAX_CACHED) {
                            removeSubFlow(eldest);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                };

        private MessageChannel createNewSubflow(Message<?> message) {
            String host = (String) message.getHeaders().get("host");
            Integer port = (Integer) message.getHeaders().get("port");
            Assert.state(host != null && port != null, "host and/or port header missing");
            String hostPort = host + port;

            TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
            TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
            handler.setConnectionFactory(cf);
            IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(handler);
            IntegrationFlowRegistration flowRegistration =
                    this.flowContext.registration(flow)
                            .addBean(cf)
                            .id(hostPort + ".flow")
                            .register();
            MessageChannel inputChannel = flowRegistration.getInputChannel();
            this.subFlows.put(hostPort, inputChannel);
            return inputChannel;
        }

        private void removeSubFlow(Map.Entry<String, MessageChannel> eldest) {
            String hostPort = eldest.getKey();
            this.flowContext.remove(hostPort + ".flow");
        }

        @Override
        protected Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message) {
            MessageChannel channel = this.subFlows
                    .get(message.getHeaders().get("host", String.class) + message.getHeaders().get("port"));
            if (channel == null) {
                channel = createNewSubflow(message);
            }
            return Collections.singletonList(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
    2017-11-20 16:54:10.712  WARN 6816 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Unexpected message - no endpoint registered with connection interceptor: 192.168.200.107:6666:46707:a02d3f05-8e32-4215-8130-29c56d25ab36 - GenericMessage [payload=byte[40], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6666, ip_connectionId=192.168.200.107:6666:46707:a02d3f05-8e32-4215-8130-29c56d25ab36, ip_localInetAddress=/192.168.200.88, ip_address=192.168.200.107, id=9031c426-438d-535d-affa-09caa09b9e22, ip_hostname=192.168.200.107, timestamp=1511193250712}]
    2017-11-20 16:54:10.712  WARN 6816 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Unexpected message - no endpoint registered with connection interceptor: 192.168.200.107:6666:46707:a02d3f05-8e32-4215-8130-29c56d25ab36 - GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6666, ip_connectionId=192.168.200.107:6666:46707:a02d3f05-8e32-4215-8130-29c56d25ab36, ip_localInetAddress=/192.168.200.88, ip_address=192.168.200.107, id=63ff31e2-8f25-8282-fec4-f3c4cfc38cd6, ip_hostname=192.168.200.107, timestamp=1511193250712}]
```

DEBUG-LOG : Client

```
19:00:35.878 [main] INFO  o.s.i.config.IntegrationRegistrar - No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
19:00:35.879 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.config.IntegrationRegistrar - The '#jsonPath' SpEL function cannot be registered: there is no jayway json-path.jar on the classpath.
19:00:35.879 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.config.IntegrationRegistrar - SpEL function '#xpath' isn't registered: there is no spring-integration-xml.jar on the classpath.
19:00:35.949 [main] INFO  o.s.i.c.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor - No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
19:00:35.950 [main] INFO  o.s.i.c.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor - No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
C:\Users\Sebas\<myApp>\client.properties
19:00:36.088 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.h.ServiceActivatingHandler - Unable to attempt conversion of Message payload types. Component 'fileManager.service.serviceActivator.handler' has no explicit ConversionService reference, and there is no 'integrationConversionService' bean within the context.
19:00:36.132 [main] INFO  o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory - started cf, port=6666
19:00:36.132 [main] INFO  o.s.i.i.t.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter - started org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter@2dd29a59
19:00:36.133 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory - cf, port=6666 Listening
19:00:36.282 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.c.GlobalChannelInterceptorProcessor - No global channel interceptors.
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.h.MessageHistoryConfigurer - Enabling MessageHistory tracking for component 'inbound'
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.h.MessageHistoryConfigurer - Enabling MessageHistory tracking for component 'outputChannel'
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.h.MessageHistoryConfigurer - Enabling MessageHistory tracking for component '<myApp>ClientApplication$ToTCP'
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.h.MessageHistoryConfigurer - Enabling MessageHistory tracking for component 'errorChannel'
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.h.MessageHistoryConfigurer - Enabling MessageHistory tracking for component '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.h.MessageHistoryConfigurer - Enabling MessageHistory tracking for component '<myApp>ClientApplication.transformer.transformer.handler'
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.h.MessageHistoryConfigurer - Enabling MessageHistory tracking for component 'fileManager.service.serviceActivator.handler'
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.h.MessageHistoryConfigurer - Enabling MessageHistory tracking for component 'serviceChannel'
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.h.MessageHistoryConfigurer - Enabling MessageHistory tracking for component 'toTcp.input'
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.h.MessageHistoryConfigurer - Enabling MessageHistory tracking for component 'de.iutp.<myApp>.<myApp>client.<myApp>ClientApplication$TcpRouter#0'
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {service-activator:fileManager.service.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'serviceChannel' channel
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application.serviceChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started fileManager.service.serviceActivator
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.g.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway - started <myApp>ClientApplication$ToTCP
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.g.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean - started <myApp>ClientApplication$ToTCP
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel - Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {router} as a subscriber to the 'toTcp.input' channel
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application.toTcp.input' has 1 subscriber(s).
19:00:36.283 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
19:00:36.284 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - started <myApp>ClientApplication.transformer.transformer
19:00:37.285 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:38.296 [task-scheduler-2] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:39.307 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:40.318 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:41.329 [task-scheduler-2] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:42.341 [task-scheduler-4] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:43.352 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:44.363 [task-scheduler-5] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:45.374 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:46.385 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:47.396 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:48.407 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:49.419 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:50.430 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:51.441 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:52.453 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:53.297 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'toTcp.input', message: GenericMessage [payload=64198e68-c701-44ae-856a-f5bf9a765e11::7d670b67-3605-4faa-908f-b9843e227b26::01717546021         ,R-Muehle            D_M72.7 keine Silovorwahl   
, headers={host=192.168.200.107, history=<myApp>ClientApplication$ToTCP,toTcp.input, id=f70a3c7b-e419-eea5-945b-0531d4acf2e0, port=6666, timestamp=1511200853297}]
19:00:53.302 [Timer-0] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter} as a subscriber to the '192.168.200.1076666.flow.input' channel
19:00:53.302 [Timer-0] INFO  o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application.192.168.200.1076666.flow.input' has 1 subscriber(s).
19:00:53.302 [Timer-0] INFO  o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory - started 192.168.200.1076666.floworg.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory#0, host=192.168.200.107, port=6666
19:00:53.302 [Timer-0] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
19:00:53.302 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel '192.168.200.1076666.flow.input', message: GenericMessage [payload=64198e68-c701-44ae-856a-f5bf9a765e11::7d670b67-3605-4faa-908f-b9843e227b26::01717546021         ,R-Muehle            D_M72.7 keine Silovorwahl   
, headers={host=192.168.200.107, history=<myApp>ClientApplication$ToTCP,toTcp.input,de.iutp.<myApp>.<myApp>client.<myApp>ClientApplication$TcpRouter#0, id=0e1ead22-e947-6ae4-bb5c-13b8fa80c5e1, port=6666, timestamp=1511200853297}]
19:00:53.302 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.s.i.i.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler - org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=64198e68-c701-44ae-856a-f5bf9a765e11::7d670b67-3605-4faa-908f-b9843e227b26::01717546021         ,R-Muehle            D_M72.7 keine Silovorwahl   
, headers={host=192.168.200.107, history=<myApp>ClientApplication$ToTCP,toTcp.input,de.iutp.<myApp>.<myApp>client.<myApp>ClientApplication$TcpRouter#0, id=0e1ead22-e947-6ae4-bb5c-13b8fa80c5e1, port=6666, timestamp=1511200853297}]
19:00:53.302 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory - Opening new socket connection to 192.168.200.107:6666
19:00:53.464 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:54.475 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:55.486 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:56.497 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:57.509 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:58.520 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:00:58.961 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - New connection 192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a
19:00:58.961 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory - 192.168.200.1076666.floworg.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory#0: Added new connection: 192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a
19:00:58.962 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - 192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a Reading...
19:00:58.962 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.s.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer - Available to read: 0
19:00:58.962 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.s.i.i.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler - Got Connection 192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a
19:00:58.963 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - 192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a Message sent GenericMessage [payload=64198e68-c701-44ae-856a-f5bf9a765e11::7d670b67-3605-4faa-908f-b9843e227b26::01717546021         ,R-Muehle            D_M72.7 keine Silovorwahl   
, headers={host=192.168.200.107, history=<myApp>ClientApplication$ToTCP,toTcp.input,de.iutp.<myApp>.<myApp>client.<myApp>ClientApplication$TcpRouter#0, id=0e1ead22-e947-6ae4-bb5c-13b8fa80c5e1, port=6666, timestamp=1511200853297}]
19:00:58.963 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel '192.168.200.1076666.flow.input', message: GenericMessage [payload=64198e68-c701-44ae-856a-f5bf9a765e11::7d670b67-3605-4faa-908f-b9843e227b26::01717546021         ,R-Muehle            D_M72.7 keine Silovorwahl   
, headers={host=192.168.200.107, history=<myApp>ClientApplication$ToTCP,toTcp.input,de.iutp.<myApp>.<myApp>client.<myApp>ClientApplication$TcpRouter#0, id=0e1ead22-e947-6ae4-bb5c-13b8fa80c5e1, port=6666, timestamp=1511200853297}]
19:00:58.963 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'toTcp.input', message: GenericMessage [payload=64198e68-c701-44ae-856a-f5bf9a765e11::7d670b67-3605-4faa-908f-b9843e227b26::01717546021         ,R-Muehle            D_M72.7 keine Silovorwahl   
, headers={host=192.168.200.107, history=<myApp>ClientApplication$ToTCP,toTcp.input, id=f70a3c7b-e419-eea5-945b-0531d4acf2e0, port=6666, timestamp=1511200853297}]
19:00:59.214 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - Message received GenericMessage [payload=byte[40], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6666, ip_connectionId=192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a, ip_localInetAddress=/10.0.8.2, ip_address=192.168.200.107, id=efd1d331-7289-5074-e6e4-d85458d0abae, ip_hostname=192.168.200.107, timestamp=1511200859214}]
19:00:59.215 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - Unexpected message - no endpoint registered with connection interceptor: 192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a - GenericMessage [payload=byte[40], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6666, ip_connectionId=192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a, ip_localInetAddress=/10.0.8.2, ip_address=192.168.200.107, id=efd1d331-7289-5074-e6e4-d85458d0abae, ip_hostname=192.168.200.107, timestamp=1511200859214}]
19:00:59.215 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.s.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer - Available to read: 2
19:00:59.215 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - Message received GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6666, ip_connectionId=192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a, ip_localInetAddress=/10.0.8.2, ip_address=192.168.200.107, id=a6807249-9f8f-16f1-53e2-e4c1b7076483, ip_hostname=192.168.200.107, timestamp=1511200859215}]
19:00:59.215 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - Unexpected message - no endpoint registered with connection interceptor: 192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a - GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6666, ip_connectionId=192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a, ip_localInetAddress=/10.0.8.2, ip_address=192.168.200.107, id=a6807249-9f8f-16f1-53e2-e4c1b7076483, ip_hostname=192.168.200.107, timestamp=1511200859215}]
19:00:59.215 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.s.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer - Available to read: 0
19:00:59.531 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:01:00.542 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:01:01.553 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:01:02.565 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:01:03.577 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:01:04.588 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
19:01:05.599 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
```

Comment: You can't call `messageHandler.start();` from the `@Bean`. You have to leave this lifecycle function to the application context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates one of the connection factories is receiving data and doesn't have a `TcpListener`.

Please edit the question to attach a DEBUG log showing both sides.

**EDIT**

```
19:00:59.214 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - Message received GenericMessage [payload=byte[40], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6666, ip_connectionId=192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a, ip_localInetAddress=/10.0.8.2, ip_address=192.168.200.107, id=efd1d331-7289-5074-e6e4-d85458d0abae, ip_hostname=192.168.200.107, timestamp=1511200859214}]
19:00:59.215 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - Unexpected message - no endpoint registered with connection interceptor: 192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a - GenericMessage [payload=byte[40], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6666, ip_connectionId=192.168.200.107:6666:51251:94af931e-65e3-498d-a88b-b7389b1df65a, ip_localInetAddress=/10.0.8.2, ip_address=192.168.200.107, id=efd1d331-7289-5074-e6e4-d85458d0abae, ip_hostname=192.168.200.107, timestamp=1511200859214}]
```

Your client is not configured to handle replies.

If you are in a request/reply scenario, you need to use a `TcpOutboundGateway` instead of the sending channel adapter.

If you want to handle arbitrary inbound/outbound messages, you need a receiving channel adapter in the client.

Comment: debug log for client is added, "showing both sides" means a log of the server too?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gary Russell and @Artem Bilan - See their answer for explanation:

Here is what i did:

```
    private MessageChannel createNewSubflow(Message<?> message) {
        String host = (String) message.getHeaders().get("host");
        Integer port = (Integer) message.getHeaders().get("port");
        Assert.state(host != null && port != null, "host and/or port header missing");
        String hostPort = host + port;

        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter messageHandler = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        messageHandler.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        messageHandler.setOutputChannel(outputChannel);
        TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        handler.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(handler);
        IntegrationFlowRegistration flowRegistration =
                this.flowContext.registration(flow)
                        .addBean(cf)
                        .id(hostPort + ".flow")
                        .register();
        MessageChannel inputChannel = flowRegistration.getInputChannel();
        this.subFlows.put(hostPort, inputChannel);
        return inputChannel;
    }
```

Thanks :)